# Python - Write to csv from a particular column number

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file Temp.csv that I am copying over to another csv file Final.csv using the following piece of code.

```
dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
csvfilename = os.path.join(dirname, 'Final.csv')
tempfile = os.path.join(dirname, 'Temp.csv')
with open(csvfilename, 'wb') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(["Title","This"])
    writer.writerow([])
    with open(tempfile, 'r') as data_file:
        for line in data_file:
            line = line.replace('\n', '')
            row = line.split(",")            
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The last 5 lines of the code are going to write to the Final.csv file from column A. I want them to write to final.csv from column D. Also I have multiple columns in the Temp.csv file. What is the best solution for this? Using python 2.7.10.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No. You did! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Answering comment. You just need to prepend 3 empty strings to your `row`

```
dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
csvfilename = os.path.join(dirname, 'Final.csv')
tempfile = os.path.join(dirname, 'Temp.csv')
with open(csvfilename, 'wb') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(["Title","This"])
    writer.writerow([])
    with open(tempfile, 'r') as data_file:
        for line in data_file:
            line = line.replace('\n', '')
            row = line.split(",")
            # there are better ways to do this but this is the most straight forward
            new_row = ['', '', '']
            new_row.extend(row)            
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: This is gonna write temp file to Final file from column 4 i.e. the first three columns of the temp file aren't written and not write to the final file from column 4. I want that in the final file the first 3 columns are blank and the entire temp file writes from the fourth column.

Comment: Can you please suggest something for that?

Comment: @amazingCodingExperience Sorry can't understand your english. Give some examples please, this may help.

Comment: e.g. my temp file contains 4 fields in the first four columns Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4. When I write the temp file to the final file, it should leave the first three columns (A,B,C) blank and write Field1 in column D, Field2 in E, Field3 in F and Field4 in G. Hope this helps!

Comment: @amazingCodingExperience see changed answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
with open(tempfile, 'r') as data_file:
   for line in data_file:
       line = line.replace('\n', '')
       row = line.split(",")         
       csvfilename.writerow([row[0]+","+row[3]])
```